# How to install Angular material last version 2.0.0-beta.10 using angular seed 2

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I installed angular material using the the get started console line from the home page

`npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk`

but I'm getting this error

> `http://localhost:5574/node_modules/@angular/cdk/a11y.js as
>   "@angular/cdk/a11y"`

this is the `"@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.10"` which requires `"@angular/cdk": "^2.0.0-beta.10",`

I dont see any a11y.js in cdk folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally got it running, I had to add some lines of code on my `project.config.ts`

```
      let additionalPackages: ExtendPackages[] = [
      {
        name: '@angular/cdk/a11y',
        path: 'node_modules/@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-a11y.umd.js'
       },

       {
        name: '@angular/cdk/bidi',
        path: 'node_modules/@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-bidi.umd.js'        
       },

       {
        name: '@angular/cdk/observers',
        path: 'node_modules/@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-observers.umd.js'        
       },

       {
        name: '@angular/cdk/overlay',
        path: 'node_modules/@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-overlay.umd.js'        
       },

       {
        name: '@angular/cdk/portal',
        path: 'node_modules/@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-portal.umd.js'        
       },

       {
        name: '@angular/cdk/scrolling',
        path: 'node_modules/@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-scrolling.umd.js'        
       },

       {
        name: '@angular/cdk/platform',
        path: 'node_modules/@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-platform.umd.js'        
       },

       {
        name: '@angular/cdk/keycodes',
        path: 'node_modules/@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-keycodes.umd.js'        
       },

       {
        name: '@angular/cdk/coercion',
        path: 'node_modules/@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-coercion.umd.js'        
       },

       {
        name: '@angular/cdk/collections',
        path: 'node_modules/@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-collections.umd.js'        
       },

       {
        name: '@angular/cdk/rxjs',
        path: 'node_modules/@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-rxjs.umd.js'        
       },

       {
        name: '@angular/cdk/table',
        path: 'node_modules/@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-table.umd.js'        
       }
```

looks like they are all require otherwise I will get a not found error, there's not `a11y.js` what I found was these `umd` in the `bundles` folder and it works with that

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue but with systemJS. I had to ad this to my systemjs.config.js:

```
        '@angular/cdk/a11y':'npm:/@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-a11y.umd.js',
        '@angular/cdk/bidi':'npm:/@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-bidi.umd.js',
        '@angular/cdk/observers':'npm:/@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-observers.umd.js',
        '@angular/cdk/overlay':'npm:/@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-overlay.umd.js',
        '@angular/cdk/portal':'npm:/@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-portal.umd.js',
        '@angular/cdk/scrolling':'npm:/@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-scrolling.umd.js',
        '@angular/cdk/platform':'npm:/@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-platform.umd.js',
        '@angular/cdk/keycodes':'npm:/@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-keycodes.umd.js',
        '@angular/cdk/coercion':'npm:/@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-coercion.umd.js',
        '@angular/cdk/collections':'npm:/@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-collections.umd.js',
        '@angular/cdk/rxjs':'npm:/@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-rxjs.umd.js',
        '@angular/cdk/table':'npm:/@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk-table.umd.js',
```

It seems there should be a better way to do this, but this worked.